# Full word should render in same Line

Tags: css, text, word-wrap

The full word is not rendering in the same line, it's breaking and rendering in two lines. Please see attached pic(Highlighted part) to better understand the CSS issue. **Zip word is rendering in two lines('Zi' in 1st and 'p' in 2nd Line)**. It should render either in Line 1 or 2. Tried some CSS for "word-wrap" but did not work out. Please help on CSS to fix this issue.

[image: Zip word is rendering in two lines]

Comment: the word shouldn't break. You have some `word-break: break-all; ` i guess. Please share code that replicates your problem not a picture.

Comment: yeah, found one property in parent div as  word-break: break-all;

Comment: When I have commented out that property, it got fixed. Thanks @MihaiT.

Comment: Glad i could help. Cheers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the word shouldn't break on a new line.

My guess is that you have a `word-break: break-all;` style added somewhere.
Remove that and it should work

```css
div {
 border:2px solid red;
 width:40px;
}
div.break {
 word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is default behavior
</div>
<div class="break">
  Here the word breaks
</div>
```